# php - sort based on date and download link for latest 5 files

Tags: php, sorting, download

I have the below code, which gives a download link for all files with a `.sh` extension. I am trying to modify it to give the link only for latest 5 files, and it's not working.

```
if ($handle = opendir('.')) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle)))
    {
        if ($file != "." && $file != ".." && strtolower(substr($file, strrpos($file, '.') + 1)) == 'sh')
        {
            echo '<a href="'.$file.'">'.$file.'</a>'."<br>";
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
array_multisort(
    array_map(
        'filemtime',
        ($files = glob("*.sh*"))
    ),
    SORT_DESC,
    $files
);
$newest = array_slice($files, 0, 5);
foreach ($newest as $value) {
    echo '<a href="' . $value . '">' . $value . '</a>' . "<br>";
}
```